# “unable to match function definition to an existing declaration” when wrapped in std::vector

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't this work? I've tried throwing an extra typename in there to no avail.

```
    class binary_reader
    {
    public:
        template <typename Type>
        Type read();
    };

    template <typename Type>
    std::vector<Type> binary_reader::read()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Well, you have `std::vector<Type>` on one side and `Type` on its own on the other... so which one is it?

Comment: `read` returns `Type` not `vector<Type>`

Comment: What kind of identity-crisis-having `read` function is this? I've never seen a `read` function return anything other than a status code or the number of somethings read.

Comment: Returning the things read is the most natural semantic for a read function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class declaration you use `Type` as return value but in your method implementation you use `std::vector<Type>` as return value.

Either change the class declaration or the implementation and it will work.